# How to watch and get new changes in a file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for a way to watch for file for addition and get the added text. I used python watchdog library but couldn't only get the events like modified, added or deleted. How can I get newly added content in case of file modification event.

I have tried python library like watchdog and watchgod but both are giving me the operation performed on file, I want content of file

````
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print("Got it!")
        print(event)
event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path='/Users/mali/Desktop/', recursive=False)
observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()```

here I can see that file got modified but how to get the what got added in file.

I am developing this to stream the changes in file to new file.
````

Comment: Depending on how big the file is, just read it and compare to the old version (which you have already read)?

Comment: thanks for the comment but I am looking for a way to stream new changes at real time